# PHP specific scraping from a class not working

Tags: php, curl, php-7

I am trying to scrape the rating from this particular page

https://www.zomato.com/ncr/between-buns-sda-new-delhi

which is in this code here

```
<div tabindex="0" aria-label="Rated" data-res-id="18559961" class="rating-for-18559961 rating-div rrw-aggregate level-7">
                                                            4.0<span>/5</span>                                                        </div>
```

I am trying to use aria-label="rated" to scrape as class has a very long name but its returning empty result

here is my code

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init('https://www.zomato.com/ncr/between-buns-sda-new-delhi');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(!empty($curl)){ //check html return

    $zomato_doc = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $zomato_doc->loadHTML($page);
    libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors 

    $zomato_xpath = new DOMXPath($zomato_doc);
    $rate = $zomato_xpath->query('//div[contains(@aria-label,"Rated")]');
        if($rate->length > 0) {
          $node = $rate->item(0);
          echo "{$node->nodeName} - {$node->nodeValue}";
        } 
        else {
          // empty result set
          echo "no result bro";
        }

}
else {
    print "Not found";
}


?>
```

But everytime I get No result bro as answer, it never parses the information. Please help

Comment: Print out `$page` and see what you get. (Hint: it's "_Access Denied_")

Comment: when u `var_dump` the `$page` its false bro

Comment: yes I get the following error Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.zomato.com/ncr/between-buns-sda-new-delhi" on this server.
Reference #18.c52bf648.1531993115.89c8f8c

Comment: if it doesn't work out, you might want to try their API too

Comment: I would but i want to use the same code to also take ratings from other rating pages of the same restaurant.